# Как получить IP и MAC адреса в сети? Работа с arp cache в linux(android)

Tags: linux, android, сеть, arp

Два дня пытаюсь понять как заполнить arp cache? Мне нужно получить ip и mac адреса всех устройств в домашней сети для одного приложения под android. Порылся в разных ресурсах. Как я понял нужно сделать широковещательный запрос в подсеть и ждать.
Ситуация такая:
Я подключен через WiFi к сети домашнего маршрутизатора. ip адрес моего устройства 192.168.0.71, а широковещательный адрес 192.168.0.255, маска подсети 255.255.255.0(то есть 254 хостов может быть как я понял).
Смотрю arp cache:

```
 
arp -a
```

Только адрес маршрутизатора 192.168.0.1, а в сети на самом деле как минимум 6 устройств.

Делаю широковещательный пинг

```
 
ping -c 1 -b 192.168.0.255
```

Пишет что 100% потеря пакетов, лол

Вновь смотрю arp cache - ничего нового.
Пытался под root и не под root.
Есть ли какие нибудь другие пути получить ip и mac адреса в сети?
Помогите плиз! По сетям не силен!

Comment: Хосты отвечают на arp запросы только посланные для поиска конкретно их ip адреса. на широковещательные ip адреса они отвечать не будут. Так что только полное сканирование сети, по отдельности для каждого адреса.

Answer (score 2):

Либо ставить `nmap` на android, либо `fping`. В общем общая схема такая: пинговать **каждый** хост в подсети (вне зависимости от его доступности), а потом уже делать `arp -a | grep`

Для nmap будет что-то типа:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0.*
```

Для fping

```
fping -g 192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы linux отвечал на широковещательный пинг, надо его включить (на каждом хосте):

```
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
```

При чём -c1 приведёт к тому, что ping завершится после приёма первого пакета и не станет ждать других устройств. Лучше ограничить время 1 секундой:

```
ping -w 1 -b 192.168.0.255
```

Сканировать подсеть перебором всех адресов можно так (под рутом результат лучше):

```
# nmap -sP -n -T5 192.168.1.0/24
```